# Will zip ties hold on a bumper for 200 miles?

Tags: camry, safety

I’m 200 miles from home for the weekend and an in-ground pipe in the parking garage tore off my front bumper (2016 Camry). We zip-tied the top of the bumper back on through the holes where the clips once were. As garages in Atlantic City are probably sketchy and closed on weekend, will zip ties hold this on for my 200 mile trip home?

Comment: Two or twenty ties? 2.5 mm or 25 mm? Can the bumper jiggle around and chafe them or is it immovable?

Comment: 3 ties (all we could fit before there wasn’t enough room to add more). They’re maybe an eighth of an inch. There seems to be very little wiggle.

Comment: Plus the left side of the bumper wasn’t completely torn away, though the right side was on the ground.

Comment: It held through the almost 4-hour drive (though we were holding our breath the whole way). Thanks for the reassuring answers— it was a very stressful experience and the responses here helped our state of mind.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up and that your vehicle (and you) arrived safely.

Comment: Now my question is, how many years are those zip ties going to hang on for? 7 years is my record up to now..

Comment: Why not shove the bumper inside the car for the trip?  Was it physically too big or did it have indicators in it?

Comment: It depends on the zip-tie.  Cheap ones will break just by looking at them.  Good quality ones could probably hold up a tank.  Depends on the weather too.  Cheap zips will get brittle in the cold.  Good ones remain tough.  A few good quality zip ties will definitely hold a bumper.  Really cheap ones, or old zips you've maybe left out in the sun for years might not.

Comment: Zip ties? Maybe I'm just old, but I thought bailing wire was the go to fix for issues like this?

Comment: @Criggie: I couldn't shove the bumper in the car as the left side was still partially attached (right side was on the ground) and I didn't want to try ripping it away. GlenYates: I had no bailing wire.

Comment: Quantity has a quality all of its own.  Simply add more - each zip tie costs around a cent.   I've also taken to carrying Velcr...HookandLoop straps because they're softer, and can be adjusted easier, and are reusable while having a more gentle failure mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using the same mounting holes which once had clips in them, the zip ties should hold just fine. If the holes are torn or lost their integrity, I doubt it will. Zip ties have a pretty good shear strength, so should work just fine. If you don't think one will do it, then put two in place. Once down the road a few miles, get out and check how ​​​​it's​​​​ holding. You should know by that time if ​​​​it's​​​​​ going to hold or not.

Comment: I think it should hold, but if you're worried, pick up a pack of slightly larger zip ties, which should be easy to get hold of. The 1/4" or 6mm ones are very strong, 4mm (or 3/16") are considerably better 2 or 3mm or 1/8".

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the zip ties outlast the car if they're not in the engine bay (heat makes them very brittle)

Answer (score 8):

Some bumpers, exhaust pipes or protective covers are run for years with a zip-tie or wire mount.

Just use large enough ties. Or a large number of smaller ties.

Answer (score 6):

**They don't have to.**

Zip ties are cheap and fairly easy to apply in a parking lot. Once you've set out on your trip, pull over every half-hour and see if they've degraded any; if so, replace them.

FWIW, that rubber thing under my front bumper came loose weeks ago, and I zip-tied it back. It's still fine, and although it's much lighter than your bumper, it's also a lot closer to the road.

Comment: Quantity has a quality all of its own.  Simply add more - each zip tie costs around a cent.